# How to play sound order by order?

Tags: java, android, audio

I need to play sound file order by order with MediaPlayer. If I use the setOnCompletionListener, the code is getting longer like this:

```
one.start();
one.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        two.start();
        two.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            two.start();
            ...three...four...
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Does it have a more practical way?

Comment: Sure, make an array (or arraylist if you do not know the length) of the one two three etc.

Comment: What is one two three?

Comment: I learned "setDataSource(arrayList)" from @Jibran Khan 
Thanks

Comment: Make sure to accept his answer if it solved your problem! (it's the green check mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only change the source of the player to next media.

```
one.start();
one.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          one.setDataSource(loopthroughSources); //may be an array or list of files path
          one.start();
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: That was the thing I was looking for. Thanks!